# Does the movie "The Dreamer of Oz" contain any factual events?

Tags: the-dreamer-of-oz

I loved this movie when it came out when I was a kid, and always considered its to be factual information that I share when referring to L. Frank Baum's life.  While I understand that some of it must be fictional, I can't really find any resources to tell what exactly has been made up or fabricated.

Answer (score 3):

If you refer to Trivia section on [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099464/trivia?tab=gf) link for this movie, you'll get to know of some factual errors in the movie. This may not be a complete list of factual errors, but at least gives you something.